# how to convert rows values to a single string

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a select statement and returns one column but many rows. I want to convert that to a single string with commas like below.

```
 SELECT CODE FROM LG_xxx_CLCARD WHERE CODE < 'KUR' AND CODE > 'CARI1'
```

this returns

```
 ASD1
 ASD2
 ASD3
```

I want to convert this to

```
 'ASD1','ASD2','ASD3'
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Your example results do not meet the `where` conditions, at least for most collations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the STUFF function:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + CODE 
     FROM LG_xxx_CLCARD 
     WHERE CODE < 'KUR' AND CODE > 'CARI1' 
     ORDER BY CODE 
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

If you need the single quotes, then the following will do the trick:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + '''' + CODE + '''' 
     FROM LG_xxx_CLCARD 
     WHERE CODE < 'KUR' AND CODE > 'CARI1' 
     ORDER BY CODE 
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: This doesn't include the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CODE , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CODE ) FROM LG_xxx_CLCARD WHERE CODE < 'KUR' AND CODE > 'CARI1'
```

The result should be

'ASD1','ASD2','ASD3', ..

Comment: `list_agg()` is not a SQL Server function.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tmp varchar(250)
SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + CODE + ', ' from LG_xxx_CLCARD 
                          WHERE CODE < 'KUR' AND CODE > 'CARI1'
```